# ubuntu server DHCP Server two interfaces -how?

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

Hi I have got a problem with DHCP Server on ubuntu server witch is configured on rasbery pi. Device has two network interfaces wlan0 -where is Internet from phone and eth0. The problem is that eth0 not working there is no internet and this interface can not give the ip address to client.
My config: yaml file

```
network:
ethernets:
    eth0:
        dhcp4: no
        addresses:
             - 192.168.222.1/24
        routes:
             - to: 0.0.0.0/0
               via: 192.168.222.1
               metric: 50
        nameservers:
            addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
        optional: true
version: 2
renderer: NetworkManager
wifis:
    wlan0:
       optional: true
       access-points:
           "Galaxy S101e88":
               password: "somepassword"
       dhcp4: true
```

isc-dhcp-server (if I try to change interface to eth0 DHCP server has errors)

```
INTERFACESv4="wlan0"
```

dhcpd.conf

```
    # A slightly different configuration for an internal subnet.
subnet 192.168.222.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
 range 192.168.222.5 192.168.222.254;
  option domain-name-servers ns1.internal.example.org;
  option domain-name "internal.example.org";
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 192.168.222.1;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.222.255;
  default-lease-time 600;
  max-lease-time 7200;
}
```